# Theorems about integrals on closed paths

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $f : \Omega \to \Bbb C$ a holomorphic function such that $\lvert f(z)-1\rvert < 1$ $\forall z \in \Omega$. Show that $$\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=0 $$
for all closed paths $\gamma \in \Omega$.

I did the following :

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \Omega$ be a closed path.
$$\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz= \int_0^1 \frac{f'(\gamma(t))}{f(\gamma(t))}\gamma'(t)dt= \int_0^1 \frac{(f\gamma)'(t)}{f(\gamma(t))}dt=\int_{f\circ \gamma}\frac1zdz$$

We have that $f\circ \gamma$ is a closed path in $f(\Omega)\subset D(1,1)$.

It is nearly done but now I am stuck because I have seen plenty of complex analysis theorems on integrals on closed paths and I am not able to tell the difference between them. Some say that if the function is continuous on a domain, then the integral is $0$ for a closed path ? Other tell that it must the function be holomorphic; or holomorphic and the closed path must contractible... Can someone maybe tell what are the correct versions of these theorems and which one is the most appropriate here ?

Comment: Cauchy's theorem states that if $\gamma$ is a contractible closed rectifiable path on an open set $G$, then $\int_\gamma g = 0$ for all $g$ holomorphic on $G$. 

In your case, the range $\Gamma$ of $\gamma$ is compact in $\Omega$, so $f$ is Lipschitz on $\Gamma$. Hence $f\circ \gamma$ is rectifiable (assuming that $\gamma$ is) and we can legitimately use Cauchy's theorem as the disk $D(1,1)$ is simply connected (in particular $f\circ\gamma$ is contractible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $z$ is an unfortunate choice of name for the last integral, since $z$ is also used  in $f(z)$. Let's call the last term $\int\frac1\zeta d\zeta$.

Use residue theorem. The function $\frac 1\zeta$ has a pole at $\zeta=0$. But your function $\zeta=f(z)\ne0$. If it would be zero, then $|0-1|=1$, is not less than $1$. So the pole is outside the contour. Therefore the integral is zero.